# JSON Accepting Blank or Whitespace for data type int

Tags: java, json, validation

Hi I am currently coding for java validation in my program, and right now if I pass Blank or a whitespace in json it accepts it and make the value to 0. Is there a way that it will not pass thru the validation if the json value is blank or a whitespace?

```
@Min(value = -1)
@Max(value = 9)
private int count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited
try to use `@NotBlank` or/and `@NotNull` in your validation. Name of the annotation says it all.

just in case that didnt fulfill your requirements the `@Digits` annotation should help.

```
`@Digits` documentation
/**
 * The annotated element must be a number within accepted range.
 * <p>
 * Supported types are:
 * <ul>
 *     <li>{@code BigDecimal}</li>
 *     <li>{@code BigInteger}</li>
 *     <li>{@code CharSequence}</li>
 *     <li>{@code byte}, {@code short}, {@code int}, {@code long}, and their respective
 *     wrapper types</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p>
 * {@code null} elements are considered valid.
 *
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 */
```

Comment: `@NotBlank` cannot be used with int. and `@NotNull` will still accepts blank and whitespace

Comment: i believe `@NotBlank` can be used. /**
 * The annotated element must not be {@code null} and must contain at least one
 * non-whitespace character. Accepts {@code CharSequence}.
 *
 * @author Hardy Ferentschik
 * @since 2.0
 *
 * @see Character#isWhitespace(char)
 */

this is the documentation for it

Comment: besides it has nothing to do with the type of the field since it will cover all fields including lists and different objects as well

Comment: i edited the answer to use @Digits it will also save you the using of `@Min @Max`